# BASH Script using awk to extract a key

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I'm creating dkim private & public keys
openssl genrsa -out dkim1024.key 1024
openssl rsa -in dkim1024.key -out dkim1024.pub -pubout -outform PEM

I have a bash script using awk to extract a key file 
KEY=`/usr/bin/awk 'NR>1{a[++k]=$0}END{for(i=1;i<k;i++)print a[i]}' file.key`

file.key contents

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqasdfadaBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBsdfadsfsDgrKE5D2atbGtaqVmAZwzy1YNY
8pUYgF6qQ4zecRrpk3Uam52asdfafasdasdfasgwYAA0x3roKIYAeHFFrFm9aCS
WKpM+na/03akmpewn4cjT4sm9qTHP0q/VM/YtHy3rGkPj+xzOKgO9rzyZo3E1a1O
HYu6TIqqzlqtadfafafafdas
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I need to remove the lines.
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
I've done this in my awk cmd but when I echo $KEY There are spaces. I'm guessing that these are return chars but I'm not sure how to get rid of them but preserve the key.

```
sh-3.2# echo $KEY
MIGfMA0GCSqasdfadaBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBsdfadsfsDgrKE5D2atbGtaqVmAZwzy1YNY 8pUYgF6qQ4zecRrpk3Uam52asdfafasdasdfasgwYAA0x3roKIYAeHFFrFm9aCS WKpM+na/03akmpewn4cjT4sm9qTHP0q/VM/YtHy3rGkPj+xzOKgO9rzyZo3E1a1O HYu6TIqqzlqtadfafafafdas
```

Thanks

Comment: change `print` to `printf`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get spaces instead of lines because of [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html). You should quote your variable around double-quotes

```
echo "$KEY"
```

This could be an alternative solution too:

```
awk '/-END PUBLIC KEY-/ { p = 0 }; p; /-BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-/ { p = 1 }' file.key
```

Output:

```
MIGfMA0GCSqasdfadaBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBsdfadsfsDgrKE5D2atbGtaqVmAZwzy1YNY
8pUYgF6qQ4zecRrpk3Uam52asdfafasdasdfasgwYAA0x3roKIYAeHFFrFm9aCS
WKpM+na/03akmpewn4cjT4sm9qTHP0q/VM/YtHy3rGkPj+xzOKgO9rzyZo3E1a1O
HYu6TIqqzlqtadfafafafdas
```

The solution would also work even if there are other lines before or after the block.

You can also do it with Bash itself:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE='file.key'  ## Or FILE=$1

KEY=()
while IFS=$' \t\r\n' read -r LINE; do
    [[ $LINE == *'-END PUBLIC KEY-'* ]] && P=0
    (( P )) && KEY+=("$LINE")  ## Store every line as an array element.
    [[ $LINE == *'-BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-'* ]] && P=1
done < "$FILE"

echo --------------------

printf '%s\n' "${KEY[@]}"

echo --------------------

IFS= eval 'MERGED_KEY="${KEY[*]}"'  ## Merge key without spaces.

echo "$MERGED_KEY"
```

Output:

```
--------------------
MIGfMA0GCSqasdfadaBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBsdfadsfsDgrKE5D2atbGtaqVmAZwzy1YNY
8pUYgF6qQ4zecRrpk3Uam52asdfafasdasdfasgwYAA0x3roKIYAeHFFrFm9aCS
WKpM+na/03akmpewn4cjT4sm9qTHP0q/VM/YtHy3rGkPj+xzOKgO9rzyZo3E1a1O
HYu6TIqqzlqtadfafafafdas
--------------------
MIGfMA0GCSqasdfadaBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBsdfadsfsDgrKE5D2atbGtaqVmAZwzy1YNY8pUYgF6qQ4zecRrpk3Uam52asdfafasdasdfasgwYAA0x3roKIYAeHFFrFm9aCSWKpM+na/03akmpewn4cjT4sm9qTHP0q/VM/YtHy3rGkPj+xzOKgO9rzyZo3E1a1OHYu6TIqqzlqtadfafafafdas
```

Comment: +1 for the awk solution but why bother posting a much lengthier and more complicated bash solution?

Comment: @EdMorton Flexibility for processing with a bash script when needed. The bash solution saves the data to the variables directly whether as a single string or an array.

Comment: Calling awk (or sed or grep or ...) from bash is still a bash script so when would processing with only bash builtins be NEEDED (or even useful)? Why would saving the data to intermediate bash variables like `LINE` and populating `KEY` from that be beneficial vs populating `KEY` from the output of awk? I'm genuinely interested in answers because I've been told for years by shell experts that there's never a case for writing a shell loop just to manipulate the contents of a text file and if that's wrong then I'd like to understand the scenario where that makes sense.

Comment: For example, read the posts about shell loops from Stephane Chazelas starting at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.unix.shell/KTVZMarkUqg/B7z0FEcGkXYJ. Stephane is vastly more knowledgable about shell than anyone I've come across, including the other people participating in that thread as acknowledged by one of the thread contributors in his book on the subject (Shell Scripting Recipes - see the Acknowledgements section at http://www.amazon.com/Shell-Scripting-Recipes-Problem-Solution-Approach/dp/1590594711#reader_1590594711)!

Comment: @EdMorton Calling external binaries slows down the script. That's one thing. When manipulating applications, files and/or filenames in a more complex manner, people would start needing arrays. If a file to be processed would have to be parsed and store as an array for later processing, using an external text processing tool would not be applicable. Check this module script of mine that processes a table of players: http://sourceforge.net/p/playshell/code/ci/master/tree/source/play/players/table.sh, and file: http://sourceforge.net/p/playshell/code/ci/master/tree/tables/players.table

Comment: You should know that many old rules no longer apply in Bash. Old UNIX shells are pretty much crappy when processing strings. Even when reading input from another binary's output line by line, best thing they could do is use a pipe which summons a subshell. Any changes made on a subshell does not reflect on a parent shell.

Comment: Calling external binaries only slows down the script when there's small input files and in that case the performance doesn't matter, but they usually speed up the script when there's large input files and when you actually need improved performance. I'm not sure I understand your other point and I looked at the script but I'm not sure what I'm seeing - it just looks like a large shell script that could have been written in awk or similar. I agree, many old rules no longer apply in bash. I suppose we'll have to agree to disagree on this one.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you WANT the input lines all concatenated into one output line or not so take your pick based on your script:

```
$ key=$(awk 'NR>1{a[++k]=$0}END{for(i=1;i<k;i++)print a[i]}' file)
$ echo "$key"
MIGfMA0GCSqasdfadaBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBsdfadsfsDgrKE5D2atbGtaqVmAZwzy1YNY
8pUYgF6qQ4zecRrpk3Uam52asdfafasdasdfasgwYAA0x3roKIYAeHFFrFm9aCS
WKpM+na/03akmpewn4cjT4sm9qTHP0q/VM/YtHy3rGkPj+xzOKgO9rzyZo3E1a1O
HYu6TIqqzlqtadfafafafdas

$ key=$(awk 'NR>1{a[++k]=$0}END{for(i=1;i<k;i++)printf "%s",a[i]}' file)
$ echo "$key"
MIGfMA0GCSqasdfadaBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBsdfadsfsDgrKE5D2atbGtaqVmAZwzy1YNY8pUYgF6qQ4zecRrpk3Uam52asdfafasdasdfasgwYAA0x3roKIYAeHFFrFm9aCSWKpM+na/03akmpewn4cjT4sm9qTHP0q/VM/YtHy3rGkPj+xzOKgO9rzyZo3E1a1OHYu6TIqqzlqtadfafafafdas
```

or use @konsolebox's awk solution, changing `p;` to `p{printf "%s",$0}` if you want the lines concatenated.